# Programmatically generate padstacks for Cadence Allegro

Tags: cadence, pad, allegro, padstack

I am laying out a complex board, with many components. One of the steps is to create padstacks for the footprints of each component. It turns out I have (nearly only) two types of padstacks to generate:

- For through-hole components, the pads are circular with a circular drill hole.
- For surface-mount components, the pads are rectangular.

In both cases, the pastemask is 0.07mm all around the pad.

The problem is that those padstacks come in about 50 different sizes. I want them to be consistently specified and typoless, and the Cadence Allegro padstack editor being awful makes generation tedious and error-prone. The obvious solution, given I only have two types of padstacks, is to script the padstack creation with the dimensions nicely specified in just one clean file.

Unfortunately, the `.pad` output files of the Cadence Allegro padstack editor are binary files, meaning that I cannot just follow a "template" and populate the numbers programmatically.

Is there a way to programmatically generate Cadence Allegro `.pad` padstacks?

Comment: Can Cadence import padstacks in anybody else's format? If so, whose? PADS (now Mentor) was one common alternative (I can't remember if they had a non-binary format offhand, but someone will) You see where this is leading...

Comment: There are also footprint libraries. They might not have everything you need but would save some of the work.

Comment: Have you tried asking Cadence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the *File > Script* command in Pad Designer to record your actions as you create a padstack. You can then use the resulting (ASCII) script file as a template, which you can run from the command line by invoking `pad_designer` with the `-s` argument.